# Anylogic: How to create an agent graph in the Main agent?

Tags: graph, distribution, anylogic, agent, measurement

In my Anylogic model I have an agent population (terminals) of 4 agents with the time measurement shown below. I want to make a graph of this `end.distribution`.

[image]

If I create a graph in that agent tab and run the model, the graph will always appear within my GIS Map in the Main agent, which makes it unreadable. Thus, I want to create the graph within the Main agent tab. However, when I make the graph in the Main agent with this histogram data: `terminals(0).end.distribution`, I receive this error: `Index 0 out of bounds for length 0`, while there are 4 agents and this reference to `terminals(0)` does work in a tab of another agent population. Does anybody know how to make it work?

[image]

Comment: Have you dragged and dropped Terminal agent into the Main?

Comment: @Yashar Yes, I have done this

Comment: Ah yes, I remember this case. You are reading the agents from DB, right? It seems like at t=0, the system has not yet created the Terminal agents. That's why you get this error. I tried to suggest you a different way..rather than reading from DB, read from txt or excel at Main -> On Start section.

Comment: Yes true that's why I get the error I think. I tried your  suggestion (with `while(terminalInfo.canReadMore()) {
ArrayList<Float> values1 = new ArrayList<Float>();
for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
float temp=lanes_reading.readFloat();
values1.add(temp);
}`) but received these errors: `lanes_reading cannot be resolved` and `The method canReadMore() is undefined for the type Excelfile`

Comment: You need to edit it for your own needs. lanes_reading is the name of the file in my model..I did not have the patience to edit everything in the code to adapt to your case.( But you get the idea.

Comment: The core idea is to read the terminal information and assign it to a 2D variable. Then you create the agents programmatically at startup like explained [here](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/agentbased/dynamic-creation-and-destruction.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I forgot to change the lanes_reading yes. However I do get these errors: `The method readFloat() is undefined for the type Excelfile` and `The method canReadMore() is undefined for the type Excelfile`. I will also try to find how reading the information and assigning it to a 2D variable works on the internet

Comment: These suggestions are way, way overcomplicating it. Replicated charts are designed to handle this problem (of initialisation order and charts 'linking to' particular agents in a population); see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is an initialisation-order one: your histograms initialises themselves before the embedded agents they are referring to for their data are created (and so you get the error).

There are various ways to control the initialisation order but the 'correct' solution here (irrespective of initialisation order) is to use a *replicated* Histogram chart, where each replication 'links' to the appropriate Terminal agent to get its data (and so will only exist when the respective Terminal agent exists in its population).

This also means you only 'code' the histogram once, and it will dynamically adjust to create as many histograms as you have agents (which is what you would typically always want).

[image]

(The expression for the X coordinate of the replicated chart will depend on how wide it is. In my case, the chart is positioned at x=40 and is 300 wide, so I make each replication 350 apart to leave a 50 gap between.)

See help section **AnyLogic Help > 2D and 3D Animation > Shape Replication** for more details on replication (a very powerful capability applicable to several different types of element).

Comment: What is the easiest way of showing the name of that specific agent (terminal A / B / ...) in this case? I already checked the box "Show name" below the Replication box, but that does not show the name anymore when running the model

Comment: Use a replicated Text element above the graph in a similar way to how the graph is replicated. (In this case, the text of the Text element will be dependent on the Terminal it relates to.) You can use `getName` to get the element's name (as on the canvas) but that's not good practice (it's very slow and is a form of 'meta-programming'): instead your Terminal agents should have a `name` Parameter or similar with some appropriate value allocated to it when you create them. And/or just use their sequence number in the population which you can get via `getIndex`.